# Csv data into table format using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have taken data from csv file using get-content
I need to print data in table format how can I do that?
CSV data looks like this after printing it in the mail.

```
ID OP_ID STATE OUP_ID METHOD time ------------ -------- ----- ---------------- ---- 2187 ab8262 working ky981 IN 09.40.13.161000 2779 ab9128 working ky359 Out 89.9 09.52.04.962000
```

Fyi: Data will be different every time

But I want to represent it as a table

Comment: Try `Import-csv` instead of get-content.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use something like this and  immediately output it into a table with `ft`?

```
Import-CSV -Path c:\temp\test.csv | ft
```

`ft` is a built-in alias of the [Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is considered as heading using Import-CSV:

```
$csvfile = Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\test.csv
$csvfile.Header1
$csvfile.Header2
$csvfile.Header3
```

Even if you want have a custom Header, then you can provide one:

```
Import-Csv -Path c:\temp\test.csv -Header 'Header1','Header2','Header3'
```

Comment: Still when I'm printing it in mail it's showing like before is there any way to print it in table format by putting lines in between

Comment: Sorry! I coudn't understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: I mean it should look like a table each column seperated by lines

Comment: Without seeing how your data looks like, its hard to assume and help. Better share your input. so someone can help you better. Thanks!